# fchown() on Windows seems to be impossible to implement in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi

*** UPDATE ***

The answers have been very helpful and now my code is returning `ERROR_SUCCESS`.  The key change seemed to be switching to use `SetKernelObjectSecurity()`.  However, now I'm seeing a different problem; my code succeeds, but if I look on the file system or check the file in code, it still has previous owner.

[This has been reported before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744721/how-to-take-file-ownership-to-the-current-user-using-win32-api?rq=1), but without a satisfactory answer.

[Here is a public gist with my code](https://gist.github.com/petrsnd/e94c6100c9f2c8c6df10).  It adds some output so you can see what I'm talking about.  You should be able to add it to an empty Visual Studio C++ Console project and debug through it.  Be sure to open Visual Studio using "Run As Administrator".

*** 2nd UPDATE ***

I just found this note on MSDN for [`SetKernelObjectSecurity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379578(v=vs.85).aspx).

> **Note**  This function should not be used when setting a security descriptor on file system objects. Instead, use the `SetSecurityInfo` or `SetNamedSecurityInfo` functions.

I'm not sure how I missed that... it's right at the top.

---

*** ORIGINAL QUESTION ***

I need to implement the equivalent functionality of [`fchown()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fchown.2.html) on Windows, but after quite a bit of research and effort I have been unable to make it work.  `fchown()` changes the ownership of a file that is specified via an open file descriptor.  In the case of Windows, this could be either an open file descriptor or a `HANDLE` (you can create one from the other).  It seems that no matter what I try, I get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

I have tried both [`SetSecurityInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SetUserObjectInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379592(v=vs.85).aspx).  I can get the ownership information from the open file descriptor using the corresponding Get* functions: [`GetSecurityInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`GetUserObjectSecurity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446675(v=vs.85).aspx).

When I rework my code to use either [`SetNamedSecurityInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SetFileSecurity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379577(v=vs.85).aspx), where you specify a name for the file rather than an open HANDLE, everything works fine.

**Have I run into the low-level file system access control rules of the operating system?**

**Is it impossible to change the ownership of an open file on Windows?**

From what I could tell, I couldn't even change the DACLs when the HANDLE was open.  **Is Windows just trying to prevent me from a false sense of security when I think I have secured the file but someone still has an open HANDLE?**

**It seems to me that if I am missing something, it might be how I am calling `CreateFile()`.**

In anticipation of some of the answers that might be posted:

(Also, please bear in mind I got this working by simply replacing the object versions of the Win32 APIs with those that take file name)

- I am running in an elevated process
- I called [`AdjustTokenPrivileges()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202(v=vs.85).aspx) to give myself `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME`
- I have been through the DACLs and the rights in my process token--I believe I am running as a user with sufficient rights (otherwise why would it work with file name)
- I tried to open the file explicitly by passing 0 to [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) for `dwShareMode`.

Here is some code.  I've removed all the error handling so that this question isn't too long:

```
wchar_t* filename = L"test.txt";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_BACKUP_NAME, TRUE);
SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_RESTORE_NAME, TRUE);
SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_SECURITY_NAME, TRUE);
SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, TRUE);
DWORD bufSize = 0;
SECURITY_INFORMATION info = OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
GetUserObjectSecurity(hFile, &info, NULL, 0, &bufSize); /* get buffer size */
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR desc = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)calloc(bufSize, sizeof(BYTE));
GetUserObjectSecurity(hFile, &info, desc, bufSize, &bufSize);
TRUSTEE trustee = { 0 };
BuildTrusteeWithSid(&trustee, newOwnerSid);
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR newdesc = NULL;
BuildSecurityDescriptor(&trustee, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, desc, &bufSize, &newdesc);
SetUserObjectSecurity(hFile, &info, newdesc);
free(desc);
LocalFree(newdesc);
CloseHandle(hToken);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

You'll need these headers:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <AclAPI.h>
#include <Sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

The SetPrivilege() function is:

```
static
BOOL
SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege) {
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newState = { 0 };
    LUID luid;
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid)) {
         return FALSE;
    }
    newState.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    newState.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege) {
         newState.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    }
    else {
         newState.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;
    }
    /* If this returns a failure then your process does not have the ability to grant the privilege. */
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &newState, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested if it works when you "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: @Havenard Yeah.  Everything I'm trying is being "run as administrator".  That is what I meant be running as "an elevated process".

Comment: Changing your full code example that you linked to use `WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC | READ_CONTROL` will allow it change ownership. Changing it to use `SetSecurityInfo` will also allow it to report errors when it fails to change ownership.

Comment: Although they recommend not using SetKernelObjectSecurity function for files, it seems that that's exactly what 'cacls' utility in Windows does. Screenshot: http://snag.gy/w2swf.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've opened the handle with `GENERIC_READ` access.  Windows enforces this; having opened the handle that way, you can only use the handle in read operations.  (This means that Windows need only check your access to the object when you open the handle; from then on, access is granted or denied based entirely on the handle's access rights.)

The [documentation on `SECURITY_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows which access rights you need on the handle in order to query and set the various information.  In your case you will need `WRITE_OWNER` to assign the ownership and primary group, `WRITE_DAC` to assign the DACL, and `READ_CONTROL` to read the ownership, primary group and DACL.

Note that `GENERIC_WRITE` does not include either `WRITE_OWNER` or `WRITE_DAC` so you will have to specify them explicitly.

(I can't find any documentation on what file permissions are included in `GENERIC_ALL` but even if it works it would be preferable to explicitly request the permissions you will be using.)

Comment: The documentation on SECURITY_INFORMATION was helpful, but I seem to get the same results whether I open the file handle with GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE.

Comment: Open the file with `WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC | READ_CONTROL` Neither `GENERIC_READ` nor `GENERIC_WRITE` are sufficient.

Comment: @RossRidge That's the right answer! You must use `SetSecurityInfo()` and you **must** open the file with `WRITE_OWNER`.  `SetKernelObjectSecurity()` does not work for files.

Answer (score 3):

`SetUserObjectInfo` and `GetUserObjectSecurity` work on "user" objects which, broadly speaking, are window manager objects.  Files are kernel objects so you need the functions with `Kernel` in the name like `SetKernelObjectSecurity`. See [Object Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724515(v=vs.85).aspx).

That said, `SetSecurityInfo` should work.

`SetFileSecurity` is working for you so you must have appropriate permissions.

Most likely, you aren't requesting the correct access permissions in the call to `CreateFile`.  Harry Johnston wrote more on this so see his answer for details.

Comment: I don't believe GENERIC_WRITE will be enough; based on the information in the SDK it doesn't appear to include WRITE_DAC or WRITE_OWNER.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I was going to double-check, then you posted your answer with more detail so I didn't bother.  I didn't delete my answer because I thought the user/kernel stuff would be helpful.  Anyway, I've now updated mine to reference yours for the permissions.

Comment: @arx The info about user/kernel stuff was helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I'd overlooked that, good catch.  (Note however that the documentation for SetKernelObjectSecurity specifically says you shouldn't use it on files, so SetSecurityInfo is the right function.)